# Python function accepting a string, but not when its inside a variable

Tags: python, regex, string, path, sequence

I have the following code (it changes the string/filepath, replacing the numbers at the end of the filename + the file extension, and replaces that with "@.exr"). I hope I made the problem replicatable below.

I was doing it this way because the filename can be typed in all kinds of ways, for example:
r_frame.003.exr  (but also)
r_12_frame.03.exr
etc.

```
import pyseq
import re

#create render sequence list
    selected_file = 'H:/test/r_frame1.exr'

    without_extention = selected_file.replace(".exr", "") 
    my_regex_pattern =  r"\d+\b"
    sequence_name_with_replaced_number = re.sub(my_regex_pattern, "@.exr" ,without_extention)
    mijn_sequences = fileseq.findSequencesOnDisk(sequence_name_with_replaced_number)
```

If I print the "sequence_name_with_replaced_number" value, this results in the console in:
'H:/test/r_frame@.exr'

When I use that variable inside that function like this:

```
mijn_sequences = fileseq.findSequencesOnDisk(sequence_name_with_replaced_number)
```

Then it does not work.

But when I manually replace that last line into:

```
mijn_sequences = fileseq.findSequencesOnDisk('H:/test/r_frame@.exr')
```

Then it works fine. (it's the seems like same value/string)
But this is not an viable option, the whole point of the code if to have the computer do this for thousands of frames.

Anybody any idea what might be the cause of this?
I already tried re-converting the variable into a string with str()
I tried other ways like using an f-string, I wasn't sure how to convert it into a raw string since the variable already exists.

After this I will do simple for loop going trough al the files in that sequence. The reason I'm doing this workflow is to delete the numbers before the .exr file extensions and replace them with @ signs. (but ognoring all the bumbers that are not at the end of the filename, hence that regex above. Again, the "sequence_name_with_replaced_number" variable seems ok in the console. It spits out: 'H:/test/r_frame@.exr' (that's what I need it to be)

Comment: "it's the seems like same value/string" Are you absolutely sure about that? Because I'm not. Compare the variable with the literal you're trying to end up with.

Comment: we need more infomation then "it doesnt work" what is the error you are getting, python is not able to know if a string is inside a variable or a string literal, so the error is probably different then you are expecting

Comment: Ah good question, when I print the variable" sequence_name_with_replaced_number
I then copy and paste whatever is in the console, and directly insert it into the function then it works.  (when it doesn't work it does not error but "mijn_sequences" prints empty)

Comment: Why does someone gives my question a minus 1? I believe the issue is replicatable with the exact same code. Do people give it minus 1 because they don't have an answer themselves?

Answer (score 2):

It's fixed!
the problem was correct, every time I did a cut and past from the variable value in the console and treated it as manual input it worked.

Then I did a len() of both values, and there was a difference by 2!
What happend?
The console added the ''
But in the generated variable it had those baked in as extra letters.
i fixed it by adding
cleaned_sequence = sequence_name_with_replaced_number[1:-1]
so 'H:/test/r_frame1.exr' (as the console showed me)
was not the same as 'H:/test/r_frame1.exr'  (what I inserted manually, because I added these marks, in the console there are showed automatically)